# How to transform a paragraph value indicating a number of points into a number's javascript value

Tags: javascript

I would like to retrieve the content of a paragraph expressing a number of points, and transform its value into a number's javascript value, so that I can add it with another paragraph's value transformed in a same way.
here it is my code which not works.

HTML:

```
<p id="paraValue">2589 points</p>
<p id="paraValue2">258</p>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
let getPoint1 = document.getElementById("paraValue").value;
getPoint2 = document.getElementById("paraValue2").value;
if (getPoint1, getPoint2 = Number (paraValue.value, paraValue2.value)
{
  otherParagraph.textContent = (getPoint1 + getPoint2) + " pts";
}
```

Comment: Use same class for all the `<p>` you want to get values of. Then use `querySelectorAll()` and `map()` it to their values. Show your html and expected output.

Comment: J'ai modifier le code pour plus de clarté. Je n'ai pas tout à fait compris votre réponse. Pourriez vous la reformuler en fonction de mes modifications, s'il vous plaît?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```js
let getPoint1 = document.getElementById("paraValue").innerText;
let getPoint2 = document.getElementById("paraValue2").innerText;

var firstPoints = parseInt(getPoint1);

document.getElementById("paraValue2").innerText = parseInt(firstPoints) + parseInt(getPoint2) + " pts";
```

```html
<p id="paraValue">2589 points</p>
<p id="paraValue2">258</p>
```

With [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function:

```js
let getPoint1 = document.getElementById("paraValue").innerText;
let getPoint2 = document.getElementById("paraValue2").innerText;

var firstPoints = getPoint1.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

document.getElementById("paraValue2").innerText = parseInt(firstPoints) + parseInt(getPoint2) + " pts";
```

```html
<p id="paraValue">2589 points</p>
<p id="paraValue2">258</p>
```

Comment: Hello! can you comment this portion of code, please? (/[^0-9]/g, '') I'm not understand this, and i never use replace method.

Comment: Very thank you. It works and it's a good solution,but, because i'm a beginner who wants to learn, can you give me back the "replace solution" in an new comment, please?

Comment: yup will add it

Comment: @PhilippeDelestan Done Check now! Btw the solution you have chosen might fail for leading space so try to trim before use!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this will help

```js
let points1 = document.getElementById("pVal").textContent;
let points2 = document.getElementById("pVal2").textContent;
let output = document.getElementById("output");

// Split the string to get just the number, then convert to an integer
points1 = parseInt(points1.trim().split(" ")[0]);
points2 = parseInt(points2.trim().split(" ")[0]);

output.textContent = (points1 + points2) + " points";
```

```html
<p id="pVal"> 2500 points</p>
<p id="pVal2">500 points</p>

<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Hello! Your solution is good and works well but there i syntax of ES6, non? [0] is ES6? I never use the ES6 syntax. But really thank you. I will work on this code.

Comment: @PhilippeDelestan the [0] is not es6 specific. The split function here returns an array of strings separated by spaces, so the [0] is just selecting the first element of that array, which is the number that you want.

Comment: Yes. Excuse me, i'm a real, real, beginner, as you can see. I really thank you. This is a good solution.

Comment: Added `trim()` to remove leading whitespace

Comment: Ah ok. i'll go precisly ask you "what is .trim()," . So thank you very much.

Comment: @KieranHarte Done!